# Why do I have the same package installed for both architectures?

Tags: apt, architecture

I have more than 1400 APT packages installed which specify their architecture as amd64. Around 180 are i386. At least some of the i386 packages have their amd64 counterpart installed as well.

I assumed only amd64 packages would be installed on a 64bit machine. Why do I have some i386 packages installed?

And, for bonus points, how does APT handle dealing with the same package in two architectures? Does it have some way of knowing those exact instances where it must install both?

FYI, I learned all this about the state of installed packages from my APT status file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All packages on an amd64 Ubuntu installed system are amd64 unless explicitly specified otherwise.

Packages that are listed as `*-i386` are compatibility packages for the `amd64` architecture which are usually needed as a dependency for an installed package.

This way, you can install a package that is available for the `amd64` architecture (the `amd64` version of an `i386` package) which is written for `i386` without having to "add" this "`foreign-architecture`".

However, if a package is listed as `*:i386`, it is an `i386` package.

---

Certain packages are only available as an i386 version. This seems to be more common with proprietary packages and so wine is often an issue here as we all know how windows won't run a lot of stuff without the x86 (32 bit) directory.

---

With that said, I believe the i386 foreign architecture is enabled by default on newer versions of Ubuntu.

You can remove the i386 versions of all the packages on your system, although, you should do so with caution as this can cause compatibility issues with applications such as Wine.

Rest assured, however, that Ubuntu and apt will always default to and install the `amd64` version of a package over the `i386` version (except for Wine). Typically, you must specify the `i386` version and if no arch is specified, the system will almost always install and use the `amd64` version if one is available and or installed.

Comment: thanks for the answer! Where are the packages referred to using the `*[i386]:(amd64|i386)` format? I've only seen the `i386` and `amd64` designations in APT index and status files.

Comment: @mac9416 One example: wine1.6-i386 which is actually wine1.6-i386:amd64. Because this is the default architecture, the :amd64 will usually be omitted. So, any package that is listed as packagename-i386 is actually packagename-i386:amd64 unless it is packagename-i386:i386. You probably do have some i386 stuff installed like libraries and other compatibility stuff like that. Most of the time, you cannot have two architectures of the same application installed as both packages will provide the same file such as /usr/bin/something creating a conflict that would need to be resolved during install.

Comment: @mac9416 Libraries, unlike executables, usually have a unique path depending on the architecture and so there is no conflict when installing both architecture library packages.

Comment: @mac9416 For applications such as wine, you can specify the architecture when creating your wine prefix and you can have more than one wine prefix for each architecture.

Comment: @mac9416 They are referred to when using the `dpkg -l | grep i386` command.

Answer (score 2):

The `i386` packages are installed on your `amd64` system because `i386` programs cannot use `amd64` libraries.

This is how `amd64` computers are able to run `i386` programs & `amd64` programs. If a `amd64` program requests for `libxml2`, the `amd64` version of `libxml2` will be called. If an `i386` program requests for `libxml2`, and it receives the `amd64` version, they are not compatible - instead, it receives the `i386` version of `libxml2`.

So the reason why both `i386` and `amd64` packages are installed, is for `i386` program support on `amd64` systems.